# Transformations of probability distributions?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am not sure where to start looking for something like this, so I am throwing it out here. Would be grateful if someone pointed me in the right direction.

The problem statement is this:

Consider two probability distribution functions $f$ and $g$.

By definition (I think) they are normalised, i.e $\int_0^1 f dx = 1$ and $\int_0^1 g dx = 1$.

Now, is there a transformation $M$ that takes $f$ to $g$: $M[f] = g$? What might be the class of such transformations and what should I refer to gain a better understanding of that?

My notation might not be appropriate, but I hope the gist of the problem is clear.

I have been reading (just barely started) Theory of Distributions by Svetlin G. Georgiev, but it seems to be too general and I wondered if there are other resources that focus on the domain (probabilisty distributions specifically) of this kind of problem. Namely, statistics and probability theory come to mind. I don't have a good background in that either, so I don't know where to look and as such any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks.